# Loop para preenchimento de dados retorna apenas os últimos valores

Tags: r

Preciso criar um programa com funções, mas não consegui fixar os comandos de repetição.

**Programa:**
Lê n o número de alunos da sala.
Para cada 1 dos n alunos deve fazer o seguinte:
Lê o nome, as notas de 3 provas P1, P2 e Psub e as notas de 3 exercícios-programa EP1, EP2 e EP3.
Em seguida calcula e imprima P (a média das provas) e EP (a média dos exercícios-programa), MF (a nota final) e finalmente a situação (aprovado, em recuperação ou reprovado em nota).

Estou bem no inicio, mas meu programa ao inserir um comando de repetição, e ao colocar para print, ele só print o ultimo dado inserido

```
n <- as.numeric(readline("Digite o numero de alunos: "))

for (i in 1:n) {
  nome <- readline("Digite o nome do aluno: ")

  p1<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P1: "))
  p2<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P2: "))
  p3<- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P3: "))
}

print(paste0(n, nome, p1, p2, p3))
```

Comment: Olá Matheus, bem vindo ao SO em português. Se está começando no site, consulte a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/) para sabe como o SO funciona, em especial o tópico sobre [como fazer boas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Do jeito que escreveu, a cada volta do *loop* os objetos nome, p1, p2 e p3 tem seus valores reescritos. Se rodar `lenght(nome)` (ou p1, etc), verá que contém apenas um valor. Crie vetores ou um data.frame com o tamanho adequado para receber os dados antes do *loop*:

```
n <- as.numeric(readline("Digite o numero de alunos: "))

dados <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = n, ncol = 4))
names(dados) <- c("nome", "p1", "p2", "p3")

for (i in 1:n) {
  dados$nome[i] <- readline("Digite o nome do aluno: ")
  dados$p1[i] <- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P1: "))
  dados$p2[i] <- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P2: "))
  dados$p3[i] <- as.numeric(readline("Digite a nota da P3: "))
}

print(dados)
```